# How to configure AWS Cloud9 to use pem key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I am trying to setup Cloud9 for an existing EC2 instance:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

it gives me a public ssh key to use, but if I put that public SSH key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` I still can't connect, it says:

> AWS Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server
>   ubuntu@ec2-xx-8-xxx-98.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

But I know ssh is available as I can ssh in manually using this command:

```
ssh -Y ubuntu@ec2-xx-8-xxx-98.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -i ~/my_pem_files/test.pem
```

so is there a way to ssh in with pem files or just the public ssh key?

Comment: if someone could tag this with aws-cloud9 that might be nice

Comment: Do your server's firewall logs and/or sshd logs report anything about the incoming connections from Cloud9? Do the EC2 security settings allow connections from any address?

Answer (score 0):

Just allow the IP ranges(that Cloud9 uses to talk to your EC2 instance) in the security group of your instance. It is as simple as that. Here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ip-ranges.html) to the official documentation.